# Uncheck a task checkbox at setup initialisation

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

In my Inno Setup script there's a task that may be used under certain conditions which are determined by code. In no other conditions this task should be executed. In fact that entire Tasks page is skipped then. Unfortunately the task selection is remembered by Inno Setup and restored on every following update setup, even if the page isn't visible at all.

I now need to uncheck that task generally at every setup initialisation in order to forget the last selected state. But I can't get this to work. Here's my latest try:

```pascal
[Tasks]
Name: DeleteConfig; Description: "{cm:Task_DeleteConfig}"; Flags: unchecked
#define Task_DeleteConfig_Index 0

[InstallDelete]
; Delete user configuration files if the task is selected
Type: files; Name: "{userappdata}\...\App.conf"; Tasks: DeleteConfig

[Code]
var
    IsDowngradeSetup: Boolean;

function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
begin
    // More code not shown here, but the following may be set under certain conditions
    IsDowngradeSetup := true;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
    // Clear possibly remembered value from previous downgrade install
    WizardForm.TasksList.Checked[{#Task_DeleteConfig_Index}] := false;
end;

function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
    // Make upgrade install quicker
    Result := ((PageID = wpSelectTasks) or ((PageID = wpReady) and (GetArrayLength(products) = 0))) and PrevInstallExists;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
    if CurPageID = wpWelcome then
    begin
        if PrevInstallExists then
        begin
            // Change "Next" button to "Upgrade" on the first page, because it won't ask any more
            WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:Upgrade}');
            WizardForm.FinishedHeadingLabel.Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:UpdatedHeadingLabel}');
        end;
    end;

    if CurPageID = wpSelectTasks then
    begin
        if IsDowngradeSetup then
        begin
            // Pre-select task to delete existing configuration on downgrading (user can deselect it again)
            // (Use the zero-based index of all rows in the tasks list GUI)
            // Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10490352/143684
            WizardForm.TasksList.Checked[{#Task_DeleteConfig_Index}] := true;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

This gives me a

> Runtime error (at 85:77): List index out of bounds (0).

I don't know where "85:77" is supposed to be but from the only recent changes it can only be the quoted code above.

I first had that in the `InitializeSetup` function but that didn't work either.

Where should I put this code so that it works and finds a fully initialised tasks list? The tasks page may not be shown so I think it's too late to wait for the page to become visible. In fact the code used to be there and wasn't called when the page was skipped.

Comment: You could resign from standard Tasks and write Checks for that and then present them as Checkboxes on specific WizardPage if needed. As at your current situation it may be that you would have to call TaskList when CurPage is Task List Page.

Comment: I have added a lot more code to my question as it seems to be required to understand why I'm doing this. Unfortunately I can't reset the task when the task list is shown because it may not be shown.

Comment: So it's as I supposed. So use the solutions outlined in my answer. I've updated it to your latest amendments.

Comment: Btw, note that the Welcome page is skipped by default in the latest version of Inno Setup. So your code in `CurPageChanged` won't be triggered.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand, why you need to reset the task. I have an impression that you have that conditional skip of the task implemented incorrectly.

It's just a guess, but I assume that you skip the task page using the `ShouldSkipPage`. So the task stays checked, if it was enabled in a previous installation.

Do not use the `ShouldSkipPage` for this, use the [`Check` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck) instead. If there's a single task only that is conditionally disabled using the `Check` parameter, whole task page gets skipped.

```pascal
[Tasks]
Name: DeleteConfig; Description: "{cm:Task_DeleteConfig}"; Flags: unchecked; \
  Check: UseDeleteConfig

[Code]

function UseDeleteConfig: Boolean;
begin
  Result := IsDowngradeSetup;
end;
```

---

To answer your actual question, you can do this:

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageId = wpReady then
  begin
    if PrevInstallExists then
    begin
      { In Inno Setup 6, you can use WizardSelectTasks }
      WizardForm.TasksList.Checked[0] := False;
    end;
  end;
end;

function UpdateReadyMemo(
  Space, NewLine, MemoUserInfoInfo, MemoDirInfo, MemoTypeInfo, MemoComponentsInfo,
  MemoGroupInfo, MemoTasksInfo: String): String;
begin
  if PrevInstallExists then
  begin
    MemoTasksInfo := '';
  end;
end;
```

Though again, I do not think, that this is a good solution.

Or even easier, use the [`UsePreviousTasks`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_useprevioustasks):

```pascal
[Setup]
UsePreviousTasks=no
```

Or similarly using the [`checkedonce` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=taskssection&anchor=checkedonce):

```pascal
[Tasks]
Name: DeleteConfig; Description: "{cm:Task_DeleteConfig}"; Flags: unchecked checkedonce
```