# Launch custom code according to selected Components in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

My query is a little similar to [Launch custom code via tasks in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281478/launch-custom-code-via-tasks-in-inno-setup/14101805) except instead of launching a secondary selection page, the variation of code is run depending on component chosen. I wish to insert variations of text into a (settings) doc. Initial attempts using the above reference code did not work, I’m guessing because inno is unable to search for a doc’s existence that early in the install process. The Append approach I was intending to use below. It appears Append does not support component flags.

```
[Components]
Name: "Adult"; Description: "Adult filters"; Flags: exclusive
Name: "PresetWordFilter"; Description: "Preset Word Filter"; Flags: exclusive
Name: "No_Security"; Description: "No filters"; Flags: exclusive
```

```pascal
[Code]
procedure ?
begin
  if ? then
  begin
    FileName := ExpandConstant('{userappdata}\LLL');
    FileName := AddBackslash(FileName) + 'lll.props';
    Lines := TStringList.Create;

    { Load existing lines from file }
    Lines.LoadFromFile(FileName);
    { Add your information to the end of the file }
    Lines.Append('xxx');
    Lines.Append('FILTER_ADULT=true');
    Lines.SaveToFile(FileName);
    Lines.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`WizardIsComponentSelected` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_wizardiscomponentselected). For example in the [`CurStepChanged` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged) (in `ssPostInstall` or `ssInstall` step).

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    FileName := ExpandConstant('{userappdata}\LLL\lll.props');
    Lines := TStringList.Create;
    { Load existing lines from file }
    Lines.LoadFromFile(FileName);

    if WizardIsComponentSelected('Adult') then
    begin
      Lines.Append('FILTER_ADULT=true');
    end;

    if WizardIsComponentSelected('PresetWordFilter') then
    begin
      Lines.Append('PRESET_WORD_FILTER=true');
    end;

    Lines.SaveToFile(FileName);
    Lines.Free;    
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using Inno 5 so I needed to use IsComponentSelected instead. Many thanks.